# Spatial Rotation in Gmod Expression2

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I'm using expression2 to program behavior in Garry's mod. [Expression2](https://github.com/wiremod/wire/wiki/Expression-2) ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111229205931/http://wiki.garrysmod.com/?title=Wire_Expression2))

Okay so, to set the precedent. In Gmod I have a block and I am at a complete loss of how to get it to rotate around the 3 up, down and right vectors (Which are local. ie; if I pitch it 45 degrees the forward vector is 0.707, 0.707, 0). Essentially, From the 3 vectors I'd like to be able to get local Pitch/Roll/Yaw. By Local Pitch Roll Yaw I mean that they are completely independent of one another allowing true 3d rotation. So for example; if I place my craft so its nose is parallel to the floor the X,Y,Z would be 0,0,0. If I turn it parallel to the floor (World and Local Yaw) 90 degrees it's now 0, 0, 90. If I then pitch it (World Roll, Local Pitch) it 180 degrees it's now 180, 0, 90. I've already explored quaternions however I don't believe I should post my code here as I think I was re-inventing the wheel.

I know I didn't explain that well but I believe the problem is pretty generic. Any help anyone could offer is greatly appreciated.

Oh, I'd like to avoid gimblelock too.

Essentially calculating the rotation around each of the crafts up/forward/right vectors using the up/forward/right vectors.

To simply the question a generic implementation rather than one specific to Gmod is absolutely fine.

Comment: What is your question/problem? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Basically, I want to calculate the rotation around each of the ships local forward, up and right vectors. ie; the ships local pitch/roll/yaw. From the vectors positions in world space.

Comment: You said you're at a complete loss on how to do it, and yet you also say that you've already explored quaternions, which are the best objects to use in such a situation (they avoid gimbal lock and can be more efficient than transformation matrices). Is it just that the code is getting too complex for you?

Comment: Essentially, I was trying to implement quaternions generically, without understanding exactly what I was doing.

Comment: I realised that quaternions are definately the method I want to go, however the problem I have is using quaternions to orientate it to a specific point, for example if the plate is knocked out of place I need to calculate the position of the thrusters (I can spawn thrusters at any point and they can point in any direction) to provide a rotational force.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the application you are looking forward to implementing, however, in this sort of situation, I would usually suggest applying angular force.  Would that be sufficient for your needs in this regard?

Well if that is all that you need, then i have managed to perfect the angular force equation to having entities point at a given position.

```
EntityVector = Entity:massCenter()    
Leverage = sqrt( ( Entity:inertia():length()^2 ) / 3 )   
LookPos = EntityVector - Target:pos()   
A = ang(  
 toDeg( atanr( LookPos:z() , sqrt( LookPos:x()^2 + LookPos:y()^2) ) ) ,  
 toDeg( atanr( -LookPos:y(), -LookPos:x() ) ) ,  
 0 )    
EntityAngle = ( ( Entity:angles() - angnorm(A) ) * 5 + Entity:angVel() ) * 5   
Entity:applyAngForce( -EntityAngle * Leverage )
```

This set of equations has helped me through countless projects

Comment: Basically I want to rotation to a specific orientation from any other orientation directly. Calculating the angular force around each axis in order to do so.